# What's the difference between Registry font list and .NET FontFamily class Families property?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create instance of FontFamily class and pass as argument names from registry:

```
    RegistryKey keySystemLink = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink");
    foreach (string fontName in keySystemLink.GetValueNames())
    {
        var fontFamily = new FontFamily(fontName);
        <...>    
    }
```

But FontFamily constructor doesn't like these names at all and throws an ArgumentException. Is that a completely wrong way? And why is that so?

Comment: Windows doesn't event use the registry to figure out what fonts are installed... so, why are you?

Comment: There is [InstalledFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.installedfontcollection.aspx).

Comment: You're apparently right, such way may be inappropriate. Do I have to use InstalledFontCollection class instead?

Comment: You see it fall over on all registry values that have "Bold" in their name.  That registry key doesn't list family names at all, it is used to find a substitute font for a specific family/style.  You'll find mostly Eastern Asian fonts in there, bold type is a Western typography style choice and not used in Eastern text.  Well, wrong key, iterate FontFamily.Families instead.

Comment: Thanks, Hans Passant, it gives me a clue about this behavior!